# Is UNALIGNED memory access required on LINUX (porting from Windows to Linux)

Tags: windows, linux

I am porting code from Windows to Linux (Red Hat Linux or Fed). In the existing code, I do find code having (datatype UNALIGNED*) reference.

Can you please let me know
1) is UNALIGNED memory access required when porting to Linux
2) If required, can you please let me know how can I achieve the same.

I have looked around for an linux version. I have come across the use of arm/unaligned.h. When I try to add the same, it gives me an error "No such file or directory".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment is a CPU restriction, not a OS thing.  x86 CPUs can do unaligned accesses (with some performance penalty), many others will produce a bus error under the same Linux (or whatever) versions if you try to load a word from something other than an aligned pointer.

The UNALIGNED keyword in MSVC is, on x86, a noop as far as I know.  On other architectures it will emit more complicated instruction sequences to make sure that the access completes successfully.  Are you trying to find a gcc equivalent?  I don't believe one exists.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've raised a SIGBUS due to unaligned access on Linux x86.  Could it be that although the CPU can handle it, it is not switched on (or off depending on your pov) in linux by default?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Some SSE instructions require aligned addresses, perhaps you used those.

Answer (score 1):

With recent `gcc` you might consider using [`__attribute__ ((__packed__))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)

But I suggest to avoid using it when possible. The compiler makes a quite good job on aligning fields. And the ABI might define rules for alignment.

You should understand why your source code use `UNALIGNED`; is it because the data has an externally defined format, or is it for "performance" reasons? Leave the optimization to the compiler!

Comment: Those are different things.  UNALIGNED is an attribute on a pointer, and it says that the pointer may be used to load or store to an address which (at runtime) is not naturally aligned.  "packed" is an attribute of a structure, which changes how the structure fields are arranged in memory.  They are related concepts (i.e. packed will produce unaligned structure fields) but you can't use one to emulate the other.